# Machine to Machine Dynamic Application Registration with Auth0

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, auth0

> I first asked this question over at https://community.auth0.com/, but
> re-iterating here to reach a wider audience,
>
> - https://community.auth0.com/t/machine-to-machine-dynamic-application-registration/96639

I'm wondering, how can I specify a dynamically created client as type Machine-to-Machine (for use with an API) at creation time? *My high-level goal is to allow developers the ability to create their own applications, then use the client credentials flow to access information via a resource server, as per OIDC spec.*

Seems like every approach requires me to manually update a "Generic" dynamic application. For instance, I can do something like

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://<tenant>.us.auth0.com/oidc/register' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"client_name":"My Dynamic Application","redirect_uris": ["https://application.example.com/callback", "https://application.example.com/callback2"] }'
```

But then it defaults My Dynamic Application to type "Generic". Ideally, i'd like to specify something like `{ "app_type": "m2m" }`, and be able to "extend" the functionality of the `oidc/register` endpoint.